# How to make the data of table kept even after containers deleted?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

My purpose is to keep data even after deleting and rebuilding containers.
More specifically, I want to keep data even after putting like "docker-comand down" or "docker-comand up -d --build".
My environment is

- Docker
- Django
- PostgreSQL
- Nginx
- Gunicorn

docker-compose.prod.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn ecap.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - ./media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  db_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

env.prod.db

```
POSTGRES_USER=nita
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*******
POSTGRES_DB=ecap_prod
```

I assume that the problems is how to write volumes in the yml file.
Although I followed the shown way, I cannot keep the data.

Comment: Your docker-compose file looks good, I think. Make sure you don't have the `-v` option on `docker-compose down` as that will delete the volumes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, even when I don't use '-v' option, the data disappears (but the volume seems not to be deleted). What do you think other problems?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the entrypoint.sh file.
In the file, there is the code `python manage.py flush --no-input`.
When I removed the code, the data can persist.